# program get EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

compilation is ok, but the program is stopped in this function. I have version for win and it function fine, but when i make version for Mac, it get this exception :(

```
 int Reconstruct(int rez)
{ //here is program stopped!!!!
```

static SDL_Surface *projekce;
 static SDL_Surface *sc; 
 static SDL_Surface *rek;

projekce = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,240,240, 32,0,0,0,0);
 sc = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, 400, 400, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0);
 // Create two arrays of unsigned bytes (chars). 4 bytes per pixel (RGBA)
 unsigned char *pixels[400 * 400 * 4];
 unsigned char *pixelsbuf[400 * 400 * 4];

glGenTextures(1, &gl_texture);// generate one texture
 glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_texture);// Set the texture

// Set the texture filters
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
 glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

int angle = 0;
 int snimek = 0;
 int i, j, k, l;// promene pro cykly

for(i=0;i<88;i++)
 {

char nazev[25] = "OUT/snimek";
  itoa(snimek, CisloSnimku);
  strcat(nazev,CisloSnimku);
  strcat(nazev,".bmp");
  rek = IMG_Load(nazev);
  snimek++;

SDL_LockSurface(rek);
  SDL_LockSurface(projekce);

//zkopiruj radek do snimku = vytvor snimek pro rotaci

for(j=0;j<240;j++)
  {
   if(j == 0) PixV1 = 0;
   else
   {
    PixV1 = getpixel(rek,j-1,rez);
   }
   if(j == 239) PixV3 = 0;
   else
   {
    PixV3 = getpixel(rek,j+1,rez);
   }
   PixV2 = getpixel(rek,j,rez);

SDL_GetRGB(PixV1,rek->format, &R, &G, &B);
   //Gs1 = ((R * 21) + (G * 61) + (B * 174)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro blue
   Gs1 = ((R * 11) + (G * 174) + (B * 71)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro green
   Gs1 = 255 - Gs1;                        //invert
   if (Gs1 < 50) Gs1 = 1;
   SDL_GetRGB(PixV2,rek->format, &R, &G, &B);
   //Gs2 = ((R * 21) + (G * 61) + (B * 174)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro blue
   Gs2 = ((R * 11) + (G * 174) + (B * 71)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro green
   Gs2 = 255 - Gs2;                                //invert
   if (Gs2 < 50) Gs2 = 1;
   SDL_GetRGB(PixV3,rek->format, &R, &G, &B);
   //Gs3 = ((R * 21) + (G * 61) + (B * 174)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro blue
   Gs3 = ((R * 11) + (G * 174) + (B * 71)) / 256;  //preved do grayscale pro green
   Gs3 = 255 - Gs3;                                //invert
   if (Gs3 < 50) Gs3 = 1;
   //Gs = (Gs1*(1)) + (Gs2*(-4)) + (Gs3*(1)); //convolution GOOD
   //Gs = (Gs1*(-1)) + (Gs2*(3)) + (Gs3*(-1)); //convolution

for(k=0;k<240;k++)
   {
    DrawPixel(projekce, j, k, Gs2, Gs2, Gs2);
   }
  }

SDL_UnlockSurface(rek);
  SDL_UnlockSurface(projekce);

gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, projekce->w, projekce->h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, projekce->pixels);
  angle += 360/88;
  Atlantis_Display(angle);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

glReadPixels(0, 0, 400, 400, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelsbuf);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

SDL_LockSurface(sc);
  SDL_LockSurface(final);

G1 = 0;
  G = 0;
  R = 0;
  B = 0;

for(l=0;l<400;l++)
  {
   memcpy(pixels+(400-l-1)*400*4, pixelsbuf+l*400*4, 400*4);
   sc->pixels = pixels;

for(j=0;j<400;j++)
   {

`PixelValue = getpixel(sc, j, l);
            SDL_GetRGB(PixelValue, sc->format, &R, &G, &B);
            PixelValue = getpixel(final, j, l);
            SDL_GetRGB(PixelValue, final->format, &R1, &G1, &B1);

            //pom = ((R/2)+(B/2)+(G*2));

            G1 += (G/90);

            DrawPixel(final, j, l, G1, G1, G1);`

}
  }

SDL_UnlockSurface(sc);

}

char fin[25] = "FIN/final";
 itoa(rez, CisloSnimku);
 strcat(fin,CisloSnimku);
 strcat(fin,".bmp");
 SDL_SaveBMP(final, fin); 
 SDL_UnlockSurface(final);

SDL_FreeSurface(final);
 SDL_FreeSurface(sc);
 SDL_FreeSurface(projekce);
 SDL_FreeSurface(rek);
 SDL_Quit();
 return 0;
}

Comment: format your code please. highlight it and click on the "{}" button. this will help other people reading it

Comment: Post a minimal, complete listing that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is highly suspect:

```
 unsigned char *pixels[400 * 400 * 4];
 unsigned char *pixelsbuf[400 * 400 * 4];
```

For one thing, those should probably be char and not char * but the bigger issue is that you are allocating enormous data structures on the stack (2.5 MB for each array, as written).  I am guessing that you are exceeding your available stack.  They should instead be dynamically allocated (and sized correctly).

Comment: For example, `std::vector<char> pixels(400*400*4);`